# Plotting data on the same axis in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a comparison of serial and parallel computation time of a rank 3 Tensor Contraction.

I have implemented the algorithm in c++. I'm using Python to run this multiple times while incrementing the matrix sizes.

I would like to make a plot using the same axis to be able to make the comparison.

```
#OpenMP Plot::BEGIN#
# Plot it with plt
plt.xlabel('Dimensions of Matrix')
plt.ylabel('Time to compute rank 3 Tensor Contraction  (seconds)')
plt.title('Serial vs. Parallel Programming Time for Rank 3 Tensor Contraction (OpenMP)')

plt.plot( args, serial_times[0], '-o', label='Serial Programming')
plt.plot( args, paralell_time[0], '-o', label='Parallel Programming')

plt.legend()

# save the plot as a PNG image
plt.savefig('OpenMP.png')

# show the plt plot window
plt.show()
```

The plot I get looks like this:
[Plot of OpenMp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIZlI.jpg)

The plot seems to have the own y-axis.
How do I get the plots to share the same y-axes.

Comment: Have you made sure that the contents of `serial_times`. `parallel_times` and `args` are floats? Normally, your method should work

Comment: @qmeeus you are absolutely right. The values returned from subprocess are decoded to string. This has resolved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)